# Mazur's torsion theorem on elliptic curves and its generalisations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves, big-picture

I want to study Mazur's torsion theorem for elliptic curves over $Q$ and its generalizations for number fields, i.e., papers by Kamienny, Kenku & Momose, Filip Najman. So please suggest to me what background I should have before starting to read the relevant papers. If you could offer me some books/papers/articles, I would be glad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Andrew Snowden has just finished teaching a course on Mazur's torsion theorem--video-taped lectures and extensive notes may be found [here](http://asnowden.com/679/).  I've watched several of the lectures; they are excellent.

Comment: I suppose the new link is this one: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~asnowden/teaching/2013/679/ (The link in the post seems to be no longer working.)

Answer (score 4):

The general case over arbitrary number fields has been treated by Loïc Merel.  A good place to start would be Bas Edixhoven's Bourbaki exposé [*Rational torsion points on elliptic curves over number fields*](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SB_1993-1994__36__209_0), Séminaire Bourbaki, 36 (1993-1994), Exposé No. 782.

There is also an excellent set of notes by Joseph Œsterlé which were to be found on the [ICTP website](http://www.ictp.it/).

Comment: I can't find the notes by Joseph Œsterlé on the ICTP website. Will you please cite the relevant link ?

Comment: @Andrew http://indico.ictp.it/event/a02005/contribution/1/material/0/0.pdf

Comment: @duje's link is in french.